# Security concerns about using bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl() to display base64 images in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, security, base64, xss

I have a working **Angular application** displaying **base64 images** in HTML using : `this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl("data:image/jpeg;base64,...")`

However, bypassing this security opens a door for **XSS attacks** such as explained in the [Angular documentation](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer).

Besides, an external company paid to find security issues in my code found those lines of code inacceptable and asked me to fix it.

Because I am not able to sanitize this base64 string image using `this.sanitizer.sanitize()` method, and because I cannot find any other way to do it on the internet, I would like to ask you how I could achieve my goal without exposing my application to XSS security issues.

Is there any other way to (filter, escape, validate) sanitize a base64 image in order to use it in an `<img>`  tag ?

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated !

Comment: What are they saying to fix it? We have run some company paid securities and if there is change they suggest it? Do you have any suggestion? Did you use some other method from `DomSanitizer ` class.

Comment: @ApoorvaChikara Unfortunatly they did not really suggest me anything else than not doing what I am doing. I do not use other methods from `DomSanitizer`. I tried to `sanitizer.sanitize()` the base64 string without success.

Comment: I am mean it is strange because this is being provided by Angular for XXS attacks

Comment: I don't think Angular provided this to _prevent_ XSS attacks, they provided a way to create a safe resource from a _localy trusted_ URL (IE, _you_ know where this URL is coming from). What Angular is saying in its doc is that using this approach may lead to potential attack. https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer#bypasssecuritytrustresourceurl